# List iteration crashes R

Tags: r, list, rcpp

I'd like to do a list iteration in Rcpp, but this code crashes R:

```
Rcpp::cppFunction('List foo(List bc) {

              for (List::iterator i = bc.begin(); i != bc.end(); ++i) i[0] = i[1];

              return(bc);

            }'
)
```

If we take the following `foo(list(a = c(1, 2, 3, 4), b = c(4, 3, 2, 1)))`, R will crash. The example above is just a dummy one - replace first element with second in every sublist (e.g. we should get c(2, 2, 3, 4) for `a` and for `b` c(3, 3, 2, 1)).

Could anyone help? I'm really new to both R and Rcpp and just going through the literature but have no idea about why the iterator doesn't work.

Comment: "Doctor, doctor, it hurts when I do this."  Maybe loop over `i=0; i<bc.length; i++` instead? Also, you can't generally _index_ an iterator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with `i[0]` and `i[1]`.  Iterators are kinda-sorta-like pointers, you need to instantiate them first.  Here is a variant of your code that works:

#### Code

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List foo(Rcpp::List bc) {
  for (Rcpp::List::iterator i = bc.begin(); i != bc.end(); ++i) {
    SEXP a = *i;
    Rcpp::print(a);
  }

  return(bc);
}

/*** R
ll <- list(a = c(1, 2, 3, 4), b = c(4, 3, 2, 1))
foo(ll)
*/
```

#### Output

```
edd@rob:~/git/stackoverflow/60291024(master)$ Rscript -e 'Rcpp::sourceCpp("question.cpp")'

R> ll <- list(a = c(1, 2, 3, 4), b = c(4, 3, 2, 1))

R> foo(ll)
[1] 1 2 3 4
[1] 4 3 2 1
$a
[1] 1 2 3 4

$b
[1] 4 3 2 1

edd@rob:~/git/stackoverflow/60291024(master)$
```

Comment: Thank you Dirk! However, then I try to continue with `for (int y = 0; y < a.size(); y++) {
                  IntegerVector new = a[y];
                  new[0] = new[1];
  }` but this doesn't compile - it says I cannot compute the `size` on it. How should I then proceed with replacing the first value with second? The output wanted is `2 2 3 4` for `a` and for `b` `3 3 2 1`.

Comment: You need `bc.size()` if `bc` is your vector.